# Создание коллекции из 20 случайных чисел

Tags: java, случайные-числа, math, hashset

Появилась необходимость создать HashSet коллекцию с 20 числами от 0 до 20. При создании с помощью кода, написанного ниже, каждый раз создаётся коллекция **со случайным количеством элементов** из случайных чисел. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так? Ведь в цикле указанно создание 20 элементов.

```
package level8;

import java.util.*;

public class task182_lev8_lec08 {
    public static HashSet<Integer> createSet() {
        int a = 20;

        HashSet<Integer> integerHashSet = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            double random = Math.random() * a;
            integerHashSet.add((int) random);
        }
        return integerHashSet;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(createSet());
    }
}
```

Comment: `Set` может содержать только уникальные элементы. Если в цикле будет создано несколько одинаковых чисел, сохранится только одно.

Comment: *создать HashSet коллекцию с 20 числами от 0 до 20* Т.е. 20 из 21 возможного? а не проще безусловно создать 21, от 0 до 20, а потом одно случайное удалить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в HashSet. Если попадаются одинаковые елементы, то он его не добавляет. Просто замените его на List, или добавьте скажем print где нибудь, вы это увидите.

Для того, чтобы оно работало вам нужно сделать так:

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter < 20) {
    double random = Math.random() * a;
    if (integerHashSet.add((int) random)) {
        counter++;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить такое решение:

```
private static Set<Integer> getRandomSet(int count) {
    return new Random()
            .ints(0, 20)
            .distinct()
            .limit(count)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: Вот, честно говоря, ничего не понятно, я только начал учить и не дошёл ещё до такого )

Comment: Это stream api. Ничего сложного - ints возвращает поток рандомных int из диапазона от  0 до 20, distinct убирает дубликаты, limit ограничивает количество элементов, boxed преобразует int в Integer, collect собирает то что получилось в коллекцию Set